# Why do sum and treatment contrasts give the same coefficients in linear regression?

Tags: r, regression, categorical-encoding, contrasts

I have been given a dummy dataset upon which linear regression is performed and treatment and sum contrasts outputs are compared.

In this scenario the coefficients are exactly the same and I don't understand how or why. They way I understand the two type of contrasts is that when you have the sum contrast your intercept is the grand mean and coefficients correspond to how much to add/substract from pairwise comparisons. The intercept of the treatment contrast conversely corresponds to y at the reference case.

```r
    obs.data <- c( 550, 604, 669, 650, 633, 601,642, 635, 1037, 
                    1052, 749, 868,1075, 1063, 729, 860)
    A = rep(c(-1,1),8)
    B = rep(c(-1,-1,1,1),4)
    C = c(rep(-1,8),rep(1,8))

    df = data.frame(A=A, B=B, C=C, Y=obs.data)

    op = options(contrasts=c("contr.treatment", 
                     "contr.treatment"))
    mod1 <- lm(Y ~ A*B*C, data = df)

    op = options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.sum"))
    mod2 <- lm(Y ~ A*B*C, data = df)
```

The coefficients I get for the two models are as shown below and correspond to what I get when calculating by hand usng the contrast.sum method.

```
--------------------------------------------------
```

```r
    Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept)  776.062      6.213 124.915 1.89e-14 ***
    A             15.562      6.213   2.505   0.0367 *  
    B            -50.812      6.213  -8.179 3.72e-05 ***
    C            153.062      6.213  24.637 7.87e-09 ***
    A:B           12.438      6.213   2.002   0.0803 .  
    A:C           16.063      6.213   2.585   0.0323 *  
    B:C          -76.812      6.213 -12.364 1.71e-06 ***
    A:B:C         18.437      6.213   2.968   0.0179 *
```

By what I was taught the intercept in the contrast.treatments case should be equal to (550+633)/2, which corresponds to all Y values where A,B,C = -1 (aka base case) divided by the total number of such cases but clearly that is not the case. Can someone please explain to me why this is not a valid interpretation in this case?

---

EDIT

Since posting the question I discovered that:

1. recoding the variables so that I have 0 and 1 instead of -1, 1 gives again the same output for both but this time what you would expect from the contrast.treatment interpretation
2. setting A and B to factor(A), factor(B) actually gives me more what I would expect as output so I guess I did not notice this is not actually treated as regression with categorical variables but with continuous ones, so my coefficients are interpreted as unit increase in y per unit increase of the predictors.

I am still not sure why I should expect the same output in the continuous predictors case.

Comment: I would have expected the intercept to be for when $A,B,C=0$.  It is not a coincidence that `mean(obs.data)` is $776.025$

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean but you are saying that the fact that the output is the same is not surprising?

Comment: No - I am saying that what you were taught about the intercept was for when dummy variables were 0-1.

Comment: I actually just realized this independently, cause I just tried to switch them out for 0,1 instead of -1,1 and I again get the same output for both methods but this time the contrast.treatment output. 

When I change the columns to factor(A), factor(B) (since I realized they are numerical). I get the correct intercepts for how  I understand the two methods and sort of more familiar output but now I wonder why they were not categorical in the first place and am even more confused. Sorry, my foundations are terrible and I am  reverse engineering this from our handouts cause I couldn't attend.